# Deploying Azure application internally

Tags: azure-virtual-network, azure-private-dns

Can anyone suggest some solution for this scenario?:

I have two resources deployed in a VNet: Application Gateway and a VM behind application gateway. (Application gateways in subnet1 and VM in subnet2) There's is no public ip associated with Application Gateway (internal app gateway with only private ip). I have automation scripts in storage account in another tenant and I need to be able to download those inside vm using azure cli. With the given architecture, I want to be able to download the scripts in the vm from storage account. Currently, if I run "az login" from VM, nothing happens. I found some help on Azure documentation :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configuration-overview#allow-application-gateway-access-to-a-few-source-ips but it's not helpful.

I have also attached network security group with allows VnetInbound for VM. In while architecture, I cannot use any public ip because of customer requirements and they do not want any connectivity to internet.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Azure VM does not attach a public IP, the storage account does not directly communicate with your Azure VM over the Internet.

In this scenario, I would like to provide two suggestions:

The one is to use [virtual network service endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview), which allow you to secure Azure Storage accounts to your virtual networks, fully removing public internet access to these resources. You could create [service endpoints for `Microsoft.Storage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?toc=/azure/virtual-network/toc.json#grant-access-from-a-virtual-network) in that VM subnet. You VM instance will access the storage account over the Azure backbone network but it has [some limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview#limitations) as below:

> The virtual network where the endpoint is configured can be in the
>   same or different subscription than the Azure service resource. For
>   more information on permissions required for setting up endpoints and
>   securing Azure services, see [Provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview#provisioning).
>
> Virtual networks and Azure service resources **can be in the same or
>   different subscriptions**. If the virtual network and Azure service
>   resources are in different subscriptions, the resources must be under
>   **the same Active Directory (AD) tenant**.

Another suggestion is to [use private endpoints for Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-private-endpoints). You could create  Private endpoint connections for the storage account in a VNet, then peer this VNet with the VNet where your Azure VM create.

For more references, you could get more details and steps on these blogs--https://stefanstranger.github.io/2019/11/03/UsingAzurePrivateLinkForStorageAccounts/

and

https://kvaes.wordpress.com/2019/03/10/hardening-your-azure-storage-account-by-using-service-endpoints/

Comment: The first approach worked for me. Thanks. I could connect to the storage account in other tenant as well as I have connected it using service principal which has access to both tenants. Appreciate your help.